# Is ASP.NET 5 which runs on linux/mac based on mono?

Tags: mono, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I want to tinker with visual studio code and c#. 
I like to test the debugging support, and while reading the documentation, i [read the following:](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_mono-debugging)

> On Linux or OS X the Mono debugging support of VS Code requires Mono
>   version 3.12 or later. If you intend to build ASP.NET 5 applications
>   with Visual Studio Code, we recommend you first follow the steps
>   Installing ASP.NET 5 and DNX in ASP.NET 5 Applications which will
>   install a version of Mono that supports debugging.

Now i'm a bit confused about .net core and mono. 
As far as i understand, .net core is the same base on win/mac/linux, but is a different code base than mono.

But since i need mono for debugging under linux, does asp.net 5 run on mono or on .net core when it runs on linux/mac?

Secondary issue: Why is there no debugging support under windows for .net core?

Answer (score 2):

.NET Core is not based on Mono.

On Mac and Linux an ASP.NET 5 application can be run on Mono or it can be run on  .NET Core. On Windows you can run an ASP.NET 5 application with the .NET Framework or .NET Core.

There is debugging support under Windows for .NET Core if you use Visual Studio. Presumably at some point VSCode will support debugging .NET Core too.

Also [currently debugging ASP.NET 5 in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/runtimes/ASPnet5#_debugging) is not supported. You can debug C# applications with VSCode using Mono but not ASP.NET 5 applications.

Comment: On the mono documentation(http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/), i don't find a reference that it supports asp.net 5 mvc 6 (Only that it partially supports mvc 5). Is it possible to run a asp.net 5 mvc 6 application on mono?